how to connect mininet to cluster sdn controllers but only 1 connection at a time
I have built physically distributed (logically centralized) SDN controllers. I would like to use Mininet to connect to the cluster controllers but want only a single connected controller at a time. Mininet should be able to switch over to another controller in case this controller is down.
How should I configure/program Mininet to do that?
I tried provide mininet 3 controllers but mininet always connect all 3 controllers at a time

I find myself solutions: Just use virtual ip (keepalived is the good one)
